# How can I set LINQ SelectMany projection via Func parameter?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function which returns a list of property values from a collection:

```
    public static List<string> GetSpeakerList()
    {
        var Videos = QueryVideos(HttpContext.Current);
        return Videos.Where(v => v.Type == "exampleType"
            .SelectMany(v => v.SpeakerName)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(s => s)
            .ToList();
    }
```

I'd like to have a generic version which will let me determine which field I'd like projected - say instead of SpeakerName I'd like to allow selecting Video.Length or Video.Type.

I understand that SelectMany takes a Func, so what's the best way to make the Func configurable to allow passing it as a parameter into this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the function as a parameter to the method.

```
public static List<string> GetVideosAttribute( Func<Video,string> selector )
{
    var Videos = QueryVideos(HttpContext.Current);
    return Videos.Where(v => v.Type == "exampleType"
                 .Select( selector )
                 .Distinct()
                 .OrderBy(s => s)
                 .ToList();
}


var speakers = GetVideosAttribute( v => v->SpeakerName );
var topics = GetVideosAttribute( v => v->Topic );
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run that:

Error 7 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Actually I don't think you need SelectMany since you're not actually selecting a collection of Speaker Names, Types, or Length.  You're only selecting a single property from each then doing a distinct on it.  It should work if you change SelectMany to Select.

Comment: To be more precise, you use SelectMany when you want to select a collection of elements from each element in the enumeration.  Use Select when you want to select a single property from each element in the enumeration.